# MySQL memory usage (InnoDB, Win)

Tags: mysql, memory

I have MySQL 5.6 (InnoDB) installed on Win 2008 server with 1Gb. mysqld uses 415Mb memory. How to reduce memory usage? I read that it is possible to do by configuring my.ini: `key_buffer_size`, `innodb_buffer_pool_size`, etc. Please, tell me the correct settings to minimize memory usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check [Configuring MySQL to use minimal memory](http://www.tocker.ca/2014/03/10/configuring-mysql-to-use-minimal-memory.html):

[image]

```
# /etc/my.cnf:
innodb_buffer_pool_size=5M
innodb_log_buffer_size=256K
query_cache_size=0
max_connections=10
key_buffer_size=8
thread_cache_size=0
host_cache_size=0
innodb_ft_cache_size=1600000
innodb_ft_total_cache_size=32000000

# per thread or per operation settings
thread_stack=131072
sort_buffer_size=32K
read_buffer_size=8200
read_rnd_buffer_size=8200
max_heap_table_size=16K
tmp_table_size=1K
bulk_insert_buffer_size=0
join_buffer_size=128
net_buffer_length=1K
innodb_sort_buffer_size=64K

#settings that relate to the binary log (if enabled)
binlog_cache_size=4K
binlog_stmt_cache_size=4K
```

Comment: Thank you! I understand that performance will be less, but I don't require very good MySQL performace right now. It should just work and don't eat all memory.

Comment: Accepted. But I should say I found one setting that helped me a lot and was not listed in the answer: table_definition_cache. In my.ini I see the comment: "The minimum and default values are both 400". But really
table_definition_cache was set to 1400. I changed it to: table_definition_cache=400 and now mysqld uses only 70Mb of memory.